# Problem with reference in python

Tags: python, selenium, class-design

```
def setUp(self):
    self.verificationErrors = []

    self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 5555, "*chrome", "http://www.address.com/")
    self.selenium.start()

def test_sel__TestCase5(self):

    sel = self.selenium
    sel.open('/')
```

and this is a part of code which I'm using in all my testcases:

```
    text='$'

    try: 
        self.failIf(sel.is_text_present(text))
    except AssertionError, e: 
        self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))
```

so now I have a lot of redundant at this moment.

I'll be grateful if someone help me to create some helper with name `SeleniumHelper` with the method Assert. Something like:

```
class SeleniumHelper:

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""

    @staticmethod
    def AssertText(text):
        try: self.failIf(sel.is_text_present(text))
        except AssertionError, e: return str(e)
```

and using it in testcases like

```
 self.verificationErrors.append(SeleniumHelper.AssertText("$"))
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: I have no idea, how write the class SeleniumHelper. The problem is that I can't use in SeleniumHelper sel from other class (testcase).

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass both self and text if you want to access self.

```
def assert_text_missing(self, text):
    sel = self.selenium
    try:
        self.failIf(sel.is_text_present(text))
    except AssertionError, e:
        self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))
```

And then you'd use it like this:

```
self.assert_text_missing(text)
```

Comment: As I see this method is this testcase class, isn't it? But, I think about other class, SeleniumHelper.